# If two pointers point to the same memory address, do you only need to use free(ptr) once or twice?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, malloc

Say we have a struct...

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));

struct node *temp_node = new_node;
```

If I use free...

```
free(temp_node);
```

Is new_node free as well (since the address no longer exists) or does new_node simply point to NULL (in which case I would need to free new_node as well) ?

Cheers!

Comment: You are freeing memory, not pointer. Surely you should do it only once.

Comment: The variable `new_node` does not "simply point to `NULL`", it remains unchanged unless *you* set it to `NULL` after calling `free`, but that bears no relation to the duplicate pointer variable, of which there might be a million, all pointing to the same memory. Match each `malloc` and `free` pair.

Answer (score 5):

You don't free pointers but the memory block(s) that you allocated - whose address a pointer points to.

With `malloc`, it returns pointer to a chunk of memory allocated that looks like this:

```
             +--------+
             |        |
new_node --> | 0x1000 |
             |        |
             +--------+
```

If `0x1000` is the starting address of that block of memory, that's what `new_node` points to (i.e., `new_node == 0x1000`).

When you assign `new_node` to `temp_node`, `temp_node` points to the same block of memory (i.e., `temp_node == 0x1000`):

```
             +--------+
             |        |
new_node --> | 0x1000 | <-- temp_node
             |        |
             +--------+
```

But there's just one block of memory that you have allocated. So once you free it via either pointer, the other is automatically invalidated and you are no longer allowed access that block of via either pointer.

In the same way, you can assign it to any number of pointers but as soon as it's free'd via one pointer, it's done. That's why care is needed when copying pointers around (because if you free one, it may still be inadvertently used).

P.S.: Free'd pointer may or may not point to NULL afterwards - it's simply undefined behaviour to access free'd memory.

Answer (score 2):

The way to think about is like: pointers **point** to a memory location.
`free()` returns memory pointed to by a pointer back to the system.
Thus if you have two pointers - once `free` is called the memory is returned to the system. You still have two pointers. And they still point to the same memory location. It's just now it is not your memory but system's :)

In short - `free` as many times as you `malloc`'d.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of exceptions, but as a general rule, there should be exactly one call to `free` for every call to `malloc`.

When you assign one pointer variable to another, you are copying the pointer value -- you are *not* allocating more memory.  So a pointer copy does *not* imply the need for a second call to `free`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are freeing memory and I see just one `malloc` here, you should only `free()` once.

In general, for each `malloc`, there has to be one and only one `free`.
Otherwise, you will get a double `free` error.

Answer (score 1):

For one memory address, you only need to call `free` once.

Once you call `free`, that tells the operating system that the memory you allocated can be used again. You do not need to call `free` on it a second time (and shouldn't, because that's undefined behavior).

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on the code

- The declarations `struct *next` and `struct *temp_node` point to an
  unnamed struct that has no instances.
- `node` is just a *structure tag* used to name the structure and
  cannot be used in an expression like this `malloc(sizeof(node))`.

If this is what you originally meant:

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
struct node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node * temp_node = new_node;
```

Then the answers provided before this post are completely accurate.

Comment: yes that is what I meant, a careless mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
}* first=NULL;

int main()
{
    first=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    first->data=5;
    first->next=NULL;

    struct Node * t=first;

    printf("%d",t->data);

    free(first);

    printf(" %d ",t->data);
}
```

In this scenario though **First** is freed in main then too **t** prints the data.
Which says that the allocated memory block can be further used for the different allocation but it's still there and can be used if a pointer is pointing to it.

But in case new allocation is made then that memory block may be allocated to the other variable. Hence after freeing the memory it's behaviour is undefined.